# Chesum example in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to get the checksum value in neo4j??

If yes anyone help how to get checksum value on two property keys:Name and Email Id using neo4j

```
  In sql--- COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(Name,EmailId))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need APOC Procedures installed, it has [utility functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_utilities) for calculating sha1 and md5 checksums on multiple values.

Since you haven't given your the label of the nodes you want to execute this for, I'll assume it's something like :User.

An equivalent query might look something like this:

```
match (u:User)
with apoc.util.md5([u.Name, u.EmailId]) as checksum
return count(distinct checksum) as uniqueChecksums
```